# When I update my field I have to replace my upload my image file. I want my image should be attahced like other field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I do not want to replace my image file while updating other text and file name should be displayed in upload file choose file section so that as per my need I can modify file. as of now I am facing issues in that I have to again upload file in each update of other field.
image for reference.
[image: Image for clarity]

**eupdate.html**

```
<input type="text" name="institution" id="institution" placeholder="Institution Name" class="form-control w-50 form-row" value="{{pi.institution}}" required>
                        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control w-50 form-row mt-1" value="{{pi.fullname}}" required>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="contact" placeholder="Personal Email " class="form-control w-50 form-row mt-1" value="{{pi.email}}" required>
                        <input type="number" name="contact" id="contact" placeholder="Contact " class="form-control w-50 form-row mt-1"  value="{{pi.contact}}" required>
                        <input type="text" name="position" id="position" placeholder="Position " class="form-control w-50 form-row mt-1" value="{{pi.position}}" required>
                        <input class="form-control w-50 form-row mt-1" type="file" id="formFile" name="upload" value="{{pi.uploaddata.url}}" required>
                        <img src={{pi.uploaddata.url}} class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="image" style="width:100px; height: 60px"><br>
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" name='checkbox' required>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
                            Agree to terms and conditions
                          </label>
                          <br>
                        <input class="bg-success text-white mt-1" style="margin-top: 0px;" type="submit" />
```

**views.py**

```
def EuAdmin(request, pk):
        pi = EmailDb.objects.get(id=pk)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            institution = request.POST.get('institution', '')
            fullname = request.POST.get('fullname', '')
            email = request.POST.get('email', '')
            contact = request.POST.get('contact', '')
            position = request.POST.get('position', '')
            uploadd = request.FILES.get('upload', '')
            pi.institution = institution
            pi.fullname = fullname
            pi.email = email
            pi.contact = contact
            pi.position = position
            pi.uploaddata = uploadd
            pi.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/eadmin")
        return render(request, 'NEC/eupdate.html', {'pi': pi})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check whether the file has been updated or not, then do things accordingly, if updated then save that one, otherwise old file should be there.

Try this view:

```py
def EuAdmin(request, pk):
    pi = EmailDb.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        institution = request.POST.get('institution', '')
        fullname = request.POST.get('fullname', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        contact = request.POST.get('contact', '')
        position = request.POST.get('position', '')
        uploadd = request.FILES.get('upload', '')
        pi.institution = institution
        pi.fullname = fullname
        pi.email = email
        pi.contact = contact
        pi.position = position
        if uploadd:
            pi.uploaddata = uploadd
        pi.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/eadmin")
    return render(request, 'NEC/eupdate.html', {'pi': pi})
```